# Clean out extra tags in HTML document converted from Word

Tags: html, css, regex, ms-word, ultraedit

I have large HTML document produced after Word to HTML conversion. HTML code contains vaste amount of extra tags. I want clean out extra tags with regular expression. I'm using UltraEdit editor (v11.20). I've tried some regular expression to find the required places in html, but not work for me.(for example '*')

Here is code sample:

```
<P LANG="en-US" CLASS="western" ALIGN=JUSTIFY STYLE="margin-left: -0.49in; margin-right: -0.59in; text-indent: 0.3in; margin-bottom: 0in">
<FONT COLOR="#943634">       </FONT><FONT COLOR="#943634"><FONT FACE="Arial, sans-serif"><FONT SIZE=5 STYLE="font-size: 20pt"><B> TEXT TEXT</B></FONT></FONT></FONT></P>
```

I want use regular expression to replace this with

```
<h1> TEXT TEXT TEXT</h1>
```

Note, there is a spacing inside

`<font color="#943634">       </font>` tags

Also, text inside `<B> </B>` tags can be long, and it can move to new line.

Comment: As we do have support issues while not able to fix it or make an try, and this looks like not even an try to make an external efforts.

Comment: voting to close this questions, because its not programming related

Comment: Don't try do do this in an editor, use a [dedicated tool](https://www.google.com/search?q=clean+up+html+from+word&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).  Word is famous for vomiting up tags and calling it HTML.

Comment: HTML Tidy for some reason just not work (I tried few versions). And dedicated online HTML cleaners can accept only small file size.

Answer (score 2):

I solved issue by cleaning out tags with Find and Replace commands, just rerun it several times.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

to delete tag p add around tag img, try:

```
function wp_bootstrap_filter_ptags_on_images( $content ){
    return preg_replace( '/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content );
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wp_bootstrap_filter_ptags_on_images');
```

...it's not all but it's a something and not is nothing...! :-)